# Left-align new to-do list items below form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using jQuery to create a to-do list and centered everything on the page using `text-align: center` with body in my CSS file. But how can I left-align newly added list items below the form?

Here's the JavaScript portion of the code I'm currently using (my guess is this is what I'd need to change), but you can also view my [CodePen](https://codepen.io/nataliecardot/pen/VXmPrO) to view the CSS and HTML.

```
$(function() {
  $('.button').click(function() {
    let toAdd = $('input[name=checkListItem]').val();
    // inserts specified element as last child of target element
    $('.list').append('<div class="item">' + toAdd + '</div>');
    // clears input box after clicking 'add'
    $('input[name=checkListItem]').val('');
  });

  $('input[name=checkListItem]').keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      $('.button').click();
      // e.preventDefault() prevents default event from occuring, e.stopPropagation() prevents event from bubbling up, and return false does both
      return false;
    }
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.item', function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're simply looking for:

```
.item {
  text-align: left;
}
```

This can be seen in the following:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.button').click(function() {
    let toAdd = $('input[name=checkListItem]').val();
    // inserts specified element as last child of target element
    $('.list').append('<div class="item">' + toAdd + '</div>');
    // clears input box after clicking 'add'
    $('input[name=checkListItem]').val('');
  });

  $('input[name=checkListItem]').keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      $('.button').click();
      // e.preventDefault() prevents default event from occuring, e.stopPropagation() prevents event from bubbling up, and return false does both
      return false;
    }
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.item', function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  background: #dfdfdf;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: #666;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #DA4453, #89216B);
}

.container {
  padding: 30px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  /* 0 is for top-bottom and auto (set to equal values for each by browser) for left-right */
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 40px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

form {
  /* needed for the same property/value to work to display the button next to form */
  display: inline-block;
}

input[type=text] {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 1.6em;
  width: 15em;
  color: #666;
}

.button {
  /* makes button display next to form */
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0 0 #fff;
  /* starts at top, transitions from left to right */
  background: linear-gradient(#f9f9f9 5%, #e9e9e9 100%);
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #c00;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 0.33em;
  /* padding is space between element's content and border. First value sets top and bottom padding; second value sets right and left */
  padding: 0.5em 0.9em;
  text-shadow: 0 1px #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: .8;
}

.item {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>To-Do List</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>To Do</h2>
    <form name="checkListForm">
      <input type="text" name="checkListItem" />
    </form>
    <div class="button">Add</div>
    <br>
    <div class="list"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Note that you'll probably also want to add some **[`margin-top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-top)** to the first element, which can be done with the **[`:first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type)** pseudo-class:

```
.item:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Adding this as well can be seen in the following:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.button').click(function() {
    let toAdd = $('input[name=checkListItem]').val();
    // inserts specified element as last child of target element
    $('.list').append('<div class="item">' + toAdd + '</div>');
    // clears input box after clicking 'add'
    $('input[name=checkListItem]').val('');
  });

  $('input[name=checkListItem]').keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      $('.button').click();
      // e.preventDefault() prevents default event from occuring, e.stopPropagation() prevents event from bubbling up, and return false does both
      return false;
    }
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.item', function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  background: #dfdfdf;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: #666;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #DA4453, #89216B);
}

.container {
  padding: 30px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  /* 0 is for top-bottom and auto (set to equal values for each by browser) for left-right */
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 40px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

form {
  /* needed for the same property/value to work to display the button next to form */
  display: inline-block;
}

input[type=text] {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 1.6em;
  width: 15em;
  color: #666;
}

.button {
  /* makes button display next to form */
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0 0 #fff;
  /* starts at top, transitions from left to right */
  background: linear-gradient(#f9f9f9 5%, #e9e9e9 100%);
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #c00;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 0.33em;
  /* padding is space between element's content and border. First value sets top and bottom padding; second value sets right and left */
  padding: 0.5em 0.9em;
  text-shadow: 0 1px #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: .8;
}

.item {
  text-align: left;
}

.item:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>To-Do List</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>To Do</h2>
    <form name="checkListForm">
      <input type="text" name="checkListItem" />
    </form>
    <div class="button">Add</div>
    <br>
    <div class="list"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I put this in the css of your pen and it seemed to do the trick:

`.list { 
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 40px;
}`

and you can tweak the margin as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

> .list {
>    text-align: left;
>   }